# When does Angular2 examine template values? How does it impact performance? [...]="complexMethod()"

Tags: performance, angular, typescript, model-binding, angular2-template

We have an Angular2 app.
I created a generic component for a group of checkboxes.

Since it issupposed to be generic, i.e. deal with a set of any objects of the same (TypeScript) class, I opted to emulate the model adapter approach known from Wicket. Not exactly, since I don't wrap it in a class, but passing individual callbacks:

```
            <wu-checkboxes [groupName]="'includedApps'"
                           [options]="availableApps"
                           [valueCallback]="appsValueCallback"
                           [labelCallback]="appsLabelCallback"
                           [equalsCallback]="equalsCallback"
                           [(checkedOptions)]="applicationGroup.applications"
                           (checkedOptionsChange)="onCheckedOptionsChange()"
            >
            </wu-checkboxes>
```

The callbacks look like this:

```
appsValueCallback = (app: RegisteredApplication) => ""+app.id;
appsLabelCallback = (app: RegisteredApplication) => app.title;
equalsCallback = (a1: RegisteredApplication, a2: RegisteredApplication) => a1.id === a2.id;

availableApps: RegisteredApplication[];
includedApps: RegisteredApplication[];
```

And the component itself has this:

```
<div *ngFor="let option of _options">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" [name]="groupName"
               [value]="valueCallback(option)"
               [checked]="shouldBeChecked(option)"
               (change)="handleCheckboxChange(option, $event)"
               />
        {{labelCallback(option)}}
    </label>
</div>
```

And

```
shouldBeChecked(option: ItemType): boolean {
    console.log("shouldBeChecked() called.", option, this.checkedOptions);
    return ...
}
```

I would expect it to be called just once for each checkbox.
But in the console, I see that **`shouldBeChecked()` is being called several dozens of times** even if there's just one checkbox during the initial rendering. I've checked that `ngAfterViewChecked` and `ngAfterViewChanged` are only called once for the checboxes component.

**TLDR:**

- Why does Angular2 call shouldBeChecked so many times?
- Does that indicate an error in how the component, page or application are set up?
- How should I figure out what's causing the calls? The stack traces are not much useful to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about it this way - (and i'm over-simplifying greatly to focus on your specific question) Angular's change detection works by listening for asynchronous events (key presses, clicks, ajax requests, etc) and whenever Angular receives such an event, it knows that it's possible that a variable binding has changed. So, it goes through all its bindings to check if the value has changed.

That means that if you're binding to the result of a function call, the only way to check if binding has changed is to call the function and check the result. And it does this on every change detection cycle (i.e. every time an asynchronous event fires).

(Again, that's an over-simplification of what's happening, but it illustrates the point that Angular has to call the function each time it needs to check if the binding has changed).

PS. Making things worse from your perspective is that in development mode, Angular actually checks every binding twice as a sort of error checking step. So, that will just add to the number of times your function gets called.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to make the instance of the component only re-render on demand? In my example, the `input` component could be notified of changes by the `wu-checkboxes` component. No need to check the changes all the time.

Comment: there's an option to change the ChangeDetectionStrategy for your component to OnPush.  Then, it will only check a component (and its sub components) for changes if the Inputs of that component change.  (see https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/02/22/angular-2-change-detection-explained.html)

Comment: Or what could help would be some kind of `isChanged()` method which Angular would ask first before examining the bindings.

Comment: Are you attempting to bind to a function that's expensive to execute? Is that why you want to limit the number of checks?

Comment: Yes, I got to a situation when it killed chrome. I had `renderMarkdown(markdownCode)` and then `Prism.highlightAll()`. And there were 10's of such blocks. I fixed/workarounded it by caching the returned values.

Comment: I was about to recommend something similar. Also look at the thoughtram article in the comment above. Depending on your use case, it may make sense to switch your change detection strategy for part of your component tree. (OnPush is basically telling change detection - don't check this part of the tree unless a component input changes, which can greatly reduce the work Angular has to do)